# Is it possible to blur input without firing the blur event?

Tags: jquery, jquery-events

I'm running into errors because an event binder in jQuery is attached to 'keyup' and 'blur'. But when I remove the input from the DOM that seems to fire the blur event, thus re-running the handler on a non-existent DOM input.

Comment: Could you put an example in jsFiddle or similar?

Comment: It shouldn't be running the event handler on a non-existent element, but rather an element that *exists*, but it is not [in a document](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/infrastructure.html#in-a-document).

Comment: @southshift: How are you removing the element from the DOM?

Comment: simple `$('input').remove();`

Comment: @southshift: Thanks for getting back, I only asked because removed elements should not trigger any events as they are removed along with them as pointed out by icktoofay above. I thought you may had used `detach()` as that leaves the events and data behind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the event listener was added with jQuery, you could use [`unbind`](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/):

```
$(/* ... */).unbind('blur');
```

In newer versions of jQuery, [`off`](http://api.jquery.com/off/) is preferred:

```
$(/* ... */).off('blur');
```

Comment: Unless the bindings are obvious and in the OPs control I wouldn't recommend to just unbind an event. What if the event was attached using namespacing, i.e `$(...).on("blur.namespace", ....)` Unbinding just `blur` then I think will accidentally unbind someone else's event bindings as well.

Comment: @FrançoisWahl: Very true. That must indeed be taken into account.

Answer (score 0):

You can validate `this` in the handler when the event is fired

`if (this && $(this).length > 0 ) { /*do stuff*/ }`